# Keep PiCamera object always active after client connection breaks

Tags: python, sockets, camera, picamera

I'm using the tremendous `picamera` package on my RPi4. In particular, the server side code

```
import socket
import time
import picamera

camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 24

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8000))
server_socket.listen(0)

# Accept a single connection and make a file-like object out of it
connection = server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('wb')
try:
    camera.start_recording(connection, format='h264')
    camera.wait_recording(60)
    camera.stop_recording()
finally:
    connection.close()
    server_socket.close()
```

as offered at [PiCamera Basic Recipes](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes1.html#recording-to-a-network-stream). This code works just fine.

I modified the code such that it

- records forever instead of only 60 seconds and
- the server socket keeps listening forever

like so:

```
import socket
import time
import picamera

camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 30

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8000))
server_socket.listen(0)

while True:  # Keep listening forever.
    client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
    print(f"New connection from {client_address}.")
    connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')
    try:
        camera.start_recording(connection, format='h264')
        while True:  # To never stop streaming.
            camera.wait_recording(1)
        camera.stop_recording()
    except BrokenPipeError as error:
        print(f"Error {error} occured.")
        # camera.stop_recording()  # If I use this line I get ConnectionResetError, and if not, I get PiCameraAlreadyRecording.
    finally:
        pass
    #    connection.close()
    #    server_socket.close()
```

I unfortunately now have the problem that I cannot seem to reconnect to the PiCamera object because of the `camera.stop_recording()`, as described in the comments thereafter. I get a `ConnectionResetError` or `PiCameraAlreadyRecording` error.

On the client side I use the code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
import datetime

server = 'http://192.168.178.54:8000/'
video_capture_0 = cv2.VideoCapture(server)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")  # Fourcc's that work under Ubuntu 22.04: mp4v, ...
date_time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
yyyymmddHHMMSS = date_time_now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S")
video_write_0 = cv2.VideoWriter(f"{yyyymmddHHMMSS}.mp4", fourcc, 30.0, (640, 480))  # To save the stream to a file.

while True:
    ret0, frame0 = video_capture_0.read()

    if ret0:
        frame0 = cv2.flip(frame0, 0)  # Flip image vertically.
        cv2.imshow('Test 0', frame0)
        video_write_0.write(frame0)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture_0.release()
video_write_0.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but in case anybody reads this, I'm using Picamera2, and you can just start the camera when the server connection is opened, and then stop it when the server connection is closed.  The rest of the time the camera is ready for use and produces stills much quicker, and is ready to respond when a new request comes in.

Not sure about picamera ver.1, but with v.2 the start method leaves the camera open and then you can capture video and stills until you manually close it.